# org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory cannot be cast to org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext

Tags: react-native

I'm seeing the following error when I try to run react-native run-android on a bare-bones project.

The same project works just fine in an iOS simulator.

I think I've got everything set up properly, as per the instructions, but I'm completely baffled as to why this is happening.  Here's the full log:

$ react-native run-android
JS server already running.
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory cannot be cast to org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

And here's the stacktrace:

$ ./gradlew installDebug --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory cannot be cast to org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory cannot be cast to org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext
  at org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingConfigurer.configure(Slf4jLoggingConfigurer.java:42)
  at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer.configure(DefaultLoggingConfigurer.java:34)
  at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.setLevel(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.on(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:42)
  at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager$StartableLoggingSystem.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:191)
  at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:60)
  at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:31)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
  at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

Answer (score 1):

This generally means gradle is loading in 2 versions of sl4j.

Try seeing if there are any slf4j.jars in /Library/Java/Extensions/.  If so, move them out and it should work.

Comment: This was the case for me. Thanks! But, I didn't actually have an slf4j jar in there--I had a custom CLI tool .jar I put in there, which had slf4j as one of its dependencies. I wonder if there's any way to stop my system from trying to import dependencies of my custom jar files...?